# Internet Explorer Form Submission issues with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-8

I have a cfform with two submit buttons, the logic in my action page works perfectly fine with safari, chrome, FF, and IE9. But IE8 and less are having issues.in IE8 or less for some reason it can’t seem to send the action page the value of the submit button, so it never makes it inside any of my if statements.

Form Code:

```
<cfform action="appQuery.cfm?loc=personal" method="post" data-ajax="false">
            <label for="fName">First Name</label>
            <cfinput type="text" name="fName" value="#fName#" style="width: 200px;"><br>
            <label for="MI">Middle Initial</label>
            <cfinput type="text" name="MI" value="#MI#" maxlength="1" style="width: 40px;"><br>
            <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
            <cfinput type="text" name="lName" value="#lName#" style="width: 200px;"><br>
            <label for="dob">Date Of Birth Ex. 03/13/94</label>
            <cfinput type="text" name="dob" maxlength="8" value="#dob#" style="width: 100px;"><br>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
                <legend>Gender</legend>
                <label for="1">Female</label>
                <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender" id="1" <cfif #gender# eq "Female">checked</cfif> >
                <label for="2">Male</label>
                <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" id="2" <cfif #gender# eq "Male">checked</cfif>>
            </fieldset>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="ethnicity" class="select">Choose Ethnicity</label>
                <select name="ethnicity" id="ethnicity" data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" class="eth" onChange="change()">
                    <option value="Hispanic" <cfif #Ethnicity# eq "Hispanic">selected</cfif>>Hispanic</option>
                    <option value="African American" <cfif #Ethnicity# eq "African American">selected</cfif>>African American</option>
                    <option value="Asian/Pacific Islander" <cfif #Ethnicity# eq 'Asian/Pacific Islander'> selected</cfif>>Asian/Pacific Islander</option>
                    <option value="Caucasian" <cfif #Ethnicity# eq "Caucasian"> selected</cfif>>Caucasian</option>
                    <option value="Other" id="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="ethCustom" style="visibility:hidden;" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="ethOther">Ethnicity</label>
                <cfinput type="text" name="ethOther" style="width: 200px;" /><br>
            </div>
            <cfinput type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Save and Contiune Later" name="submit"  />
            <cfinput type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Save and Contiune Now" name="submit" />
        </cfform>
```

Action page:

```
<cfif #URL.loc# eq "personal" AND #FORM.submit# eq "Save and Contiune Now">
    <cfquery datasource="#dbname#" username="#dbuser#" password="#dbpass#" name="personal1">
    UPDATE student
    SET  fName = '#FORM.fName#', lName = '#FORM.lName#', MI = '#FORM.MI#', dob = '#FORM.dob#', gender = '#FORM.gender#',<cfif #FORM.ethnicity# eq "Other"> Ethnicity = '#FORM.ethOther#'<cfelse> Ethnicity = '#FORM.ethnicity#'</cfif>
    WHERE s_id = '#COOKIE.id#'
    </cfquery>
    <cflocation url="appProcess.cfm##contact" addtoken="no">
<cfelseif #URL.loc# eq "personal" AND #FORM.submit# eq "Save and Contiune Later">
    <cfquery datasource="#dbname#" username="#dbuser#" password="#dbpass#">
    UPDATE student
    SET  fName = '#FORM.fName#', lName = '#FORM.lName#', MI = '#FORM.MI#', dob = '#FORM.dob#', gender = '#FORM.gender#',<cfif #FORM.ethnicity# eq "Other"> Ethnicity = '#FORM.ethOther#'<cfelse> Ethnicity = '#FORM.ethnicity#'</cfif>
    WHERE s_id = '#COOKIE.id#'
    </cfquery>
    <cflocation url="http://.com/logout.cfm" addtoken="no”>
</cfif>
```

Is there a different way I could conditionally check for which submit button that was pressed that is IE friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check it out the following coding. Hope it can help you.

**Form Page**

```
<script>
<!-- 
    function clickbtnSubmit(obj) {
        document.myForm.btnPress.value = obj;
    }
 -->
</script>

<cfform name="myForm" action="[yourActionPage]" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <input type="Hidden" name="btnPress">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <cfinput type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Save and Contiune Later" onclick="clickbtnSubmit(this.value)" name="submit"  />
    <cfinput type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Save and Contiune Now" onclick="clickbtnSubmit(this.value)" name="submit" />
</cfform>
```

**Action Page**

```
<cfdump var="#form#">
```

Comment: a couple questions probably stupid questions, but why is the function in html comments? And also what does the cfdump tag do?

Comment: Don't case HTML comment. what I put <cfdump> is to let you know which submit button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the submits to buttons, then catch an onclick on whichever button was pressed, change a hidden form field then submit.

Or, just change the two submit buttons into radio inputs?

Comment: I might want to point out as well, you have UN-parametrized values inside your cfquery's, which can lead to SQL Injection.. and you just posted your URLs.

Comment: I’m relativity new to coldfusion, what are parameterizted values in cfqueries? Also could you show me pseudo code javascript on your answer I am having a hard time figuring out how that function would work.

Comment: Inside of your cfquery's, do this:
<cfquery database="foo">
UPDATE student
set fName = <cfqueryparam value="#form.fName#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
</cfquery>

Comment: how exactly does this prevent sql injection?

Comment: More information at http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_18.html

Comment: As for changing values before submit, see these
http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1116160.htm
http://www.justskins.com/forums/how-to-submit-form-20730.html
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/submit-form-and-change-value-javascript-function-t1250688.html
http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%2C+change+value+before+submit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: You might also want to use maxlength in the your cfqueryparam tag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help:  I'm using IE version 8.0.6001.18702 and I noticed the submit button is not passed when I pressed the enter key instead of pressing the "submit" button.  I don't have this problem in Chrome or Firefox.  A simple fix is to create a hidden dummy field to pass and check for the value which only requires you to add one line and change one line on the same CF page.

The 2 lines are:
1.  Passing of a dummy field by adding one line where you pass the hidden field (see next to last line; I used the variable name enter) 
2.  Add the checking of the existence of the dummy value, "form.enter" at the top of your code (see first line of sample code)

Sample code:   my_edit_page.cfm

```
<cfif isdefined("form.update") OR isdefined("form.enter")>
    <cfquery datasource="my_datasource" result="sqlerrm">
         [enter your SQL here]
     </cfquery>
     <cflocation url="my_edit_page.cfm?id=#url.id# />
</cfif>
 :
 :            
<cfform action="my_edit_page.cfm" method="post">

         :
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" value="Update" />
     <input type="hidden" name="my_field" value="#myquery.my_field#" /> 
     <input type="hidden" name="enter" value="enter" />
</cfform>
:
```